# GET http://localhost:8563/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NEsUPis 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, p5.js

I've spent days trying to figure out why this is not working, but I didn't get anything out of it.
I tried some other answers about this topic, but none seemed to work for me.
Answers tried:
[How to resolve a Socket.io 404 (Not Found) error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393705/how-to-resolve-a-socket-io-404-not-found-error)

[socket.io: Failed to load resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653237/socket-io-failed-to-load-resource)

[GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981396/get-http-localhost3000-socket-io-socket-io-js-404-not-found)

[Error: http://localhost:3001/socket.io/ 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068716/error-http-localhost3001-socket-io-404-not-found)

[Socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found) - How to configure socket.IO - nodejs, apache2, websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846572/socket-io-http-localhost3000-socket-io-socket-io-js-404-not-found-how-to)

[Socket.io 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913881/socket-io-404-not-found)

This is my code.
File server.js:

```
//Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//Dependencies

//Global variables
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;
const ROOT = {root : __dirname};
var players = [];
//Global variables

var server = app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log("Server process started successfully on port " + PORT + "\n");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Server called from " + req.socket.remoteAddress + ":" + req.socket.remotePort + "\n");
    res.sendFile('html/access.html', ROOT);
});

app.get('/gameSelection', function(req, res) {
    let name = req.query.name;
    players.push(name);
    console.log("New player named " + name + " joined the hub." + "\n");
    console.log("Total active players: " + players.length + "\n");
    console.log("Complete list of active players: " + players + "\n");
    res.sendFile('sketches/menu/index.html', ROOT);
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/sketches/menu'));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("We have a new client: " + socket.id);
});
```

File access.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome traveler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="/gameSelection">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Insert your name..." required>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

File menu.js:

```
const socket = io.connect(window.location.origin);

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(600, 400);
    ellipse(100, 100, 50, 50);
}

function draw() {}
```

File index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>

  <style> body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As shown by the code, I'm trying to connect via socket.io a p5js page to my node server.
But when I get to the index.html page I get this error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NEsXBrx 404 (Not Found)
> Request.create @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Request @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> XHR.request @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> XHR.doPoll @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Polling.poll @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Polling.doOpen @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Transport.open @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Socket.open @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Socket @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Socket @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:1
> Manager.open.Manager.connect @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:2
> (anonymous) @ socket.io-1.4.5.js:3

I really cannot understand what's wrong with my code, so I hope someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never set the ``"port"`` setting on your Express app.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes doesn't _app.listen()_ set the port for my Express app?

Comment: No, it doesn't. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen. And anyways, you are creating your ``Socket.IO`` server before the app starts listening, so the port will be ``undefined``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing this line of code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Before `server` has a value.  So, you end up doing this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(undefined);
```

Which will probably create a separate web server on a default port which isn't the port you're trying to connect on.

---

You need to execute this line of code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

AFTER `server` already has a value.

Note, if you use `const` and `let` and get rid of all occurrences of `var`, then Javascript would appropriately tell you this was an error because you're attempting to use the variable before it's declaration.  That is technically legal with `var`, but obviously leads to programming mistakes like this.  Use `let` and `const` instead of `var` and you can't make this type of mistake nearly as easily.

Comment: Thank you, solved my issue. Very stupid mistake ahah